# How to show the tweets of a current logged in user on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app, that when a user is logged into his account, he can view his top 5 or 10 tweets of his account.

I've used the Omniauth Gem to connect my app with Twitter and also have saved the auth_token and auth_secret of user (When user allowed) to App.

Now I want to show the tweets of that user by using this auth token and secret.

I went through the twitter gem but didn't get any specific method to fetch the tweets of user.

How can I do that?

Comment: Really? You can't see anything on http://twitter.rubyforge.org/ that looks like it gets a user's tweets?

Comment: Yes Now I am able to access the tweet also the protected tweets.I didn't read the doc carefully. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [twitter gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of my query:-

This is the methods available in the Gem twitter.

Ex:-

Twitter.user_timeline("gsoniscs").each do |tweet| 
 puts tweet.text;
end